# Add Edges collection to a graph

Tags: php, graph, arangodb

Using Arangodb 3.2, have a set of collections (arangoimp + CSV):

- user (documents)
- profile (documents)
- user_profile (edges)

I'd like create a graph from listed above. Was unable to find in the documentation about composing graph from already existent collections of vertices and edges, or didn't get how to.

In [1] there is an example how to add relation (e.g. create edges collection, linking vertices), but what if I already have one?

It would be nice to understand how to compose a graph from existent collections via (AND/OR):

- PHP (triagens/arangodb)
- HTTP API
- Bash

Links:

1. https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/graphs/general-graphs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a PHP solution myself:

```
$edgeDefinition = new \triagens\ArangoDb\EdgeDefinition(
   'user_profile',
   'user',
   'profile'
);

$graphName = 'testGraph';
$graph = new \triagens\ArangoDb\Graph($graphName);
$graph->addEdgeDefinition($edgeDefinition);

$graphHandler = new \triagens\ArangoDb\GraphHandler($connection);

if (!$graphHandler->getGraph($graphName)) {
    $graphHandler->createGraph($graph);
}
```

I'd propose update official docs (see [1]) with more explicit explanation of *graph_module._relation* parameters.

It's a pity, but there is no ArangoDb HTTP API solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create the graph via the web interface (https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/web-interface/graphs/)?

If you want to create the graph just once this is an easy solution.

Comment: Thank you, but I need create one on regular basis, so PHP, or HTTP API is the best solution.